# Append 300.000 lines or print them into a file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I need to get from thousands of online JSON about 300.000 final lines, equal to 30MB.

Being beginner in coding, I prefer to stick to JS to $getJSON data, cut it, append interesting parts to my `<body>`, and loop on the thousands online JSON. But I wonder :

1. **can my web-browser handles 300.000 $getJSON queries and the resulting 30~50MB webpage without crashing ?**
2. **is it possible to use JS to write down a file with this results, so the script's works is constantly saved ?**

I expect my script to run about 24 hours. Numbers are estimations.

**Edit:** I don't have server side knowledge, just JS.

Comment: 1) Did you try it find out? 2) Can't you get the server to save the file? If not, [HTML5 file system api](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)

Comment: Is it necessary to do this task with the browser?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make the JSON calls on the server side and just output the results to a webpage? Maybe page through them so you don't wind up with 30mb on a single page?

Comment: @Tim: The rep limit on commenting is to prevent you from commenting until you have more experience with the site; it is _not_ to encourage you to workaround this by writing your comment in other, inappropriate places!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things aren't right about your approach for this:

1. If what you are doing is fetching (and processing) data from another source then displaying it for a visitor, processing of this scale should be done separately and beforehand in a background process. Web browsers should not be used as data processors on the scale you're talking about.
2. If you try to display a 30-50MB webpage, your user is going to experience *lots* of frustrating issues - browser crashes, lack of responsiveness, timeouts, long load times, and so on. If you expect any users on older IE browsers, they might as well give up without even trying.

My recommendation is to pull this task out and do it using your backend infrastructure, saving the results in a database which can then be searched, filtered, and accessed by your user. Some options worth looking into:

#### Cron

Cron will allow you to run a task on a repeated and regular basis, such as daily or hourly. Use this if you want to continually update your dataset.

#### Worker (Heroku)

If running Heroku, take it out of the dyno and use a separate worker so as not to clog up any existing traffic on your app.

Comment: The only user will be myself, once. Being a linguist, my coding skills are JS, some tiny bits of python. So I try to stick on JS.

Comment: In that case, have your local server run the process then either 1) send data (preferably paginated at least) to your browser, or 2) have your backend create a file you can then access directly.

Comment: In light of your JS/Python update, all I can recommend is to try it and see if you get acceptable results. But, it may make sense to create a file and add to that file periodically (say every 50 requests) so your work is 'saved'.

Comment: This interest me, may you give me some keywords for creating file / writing them using JS ?

Comment: I would recommend you try Googling it, then post a separate question about this if you still need help.